# Is it normal that answer to Community Wiki question aren't automatically turned to Community Wiki ?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-wiki

Some question are Community Wiki, but because they where switch to Community Wiki after a couple of post, the first answers aren't Community Wiki. Is it a bug or it's intended ?

Example :

[What online computer language interpreters are available, so I can practice programming from my iPhone?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1953/what-online-computer-language-interpreters-are-available-so-i-can-practice-progr/1958#1958)
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2050/what-is-your-most-used-webapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Crossbrowser notes, this can happen, and is normal..ish.

If you feel strongly that the answers should be wiki, you can flag these for moderator attention and we can turn them all to wiki.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's normal. If the answers were posted before the question was turned into a community wiki, the answers will remain normal, but subsequent answers will automatically be community wiki.